# Multiselect no carga datos

Tags: vue.js

estoy realizando una aplicacion en vue y he realizo el siguiente multiselect para recuperar los datos :

```
<div class="col-4">
                <label class="container">Seleccionar Casa</label> 
                <multiselect
                    class="selectpicker" 
                    v-model="optionValues"
                    :options="options" 
                    :clear-on-select="false"
                    :preserve-search="true" 
                    :multiple="false"
                    placeholder="Selecciona un habitatge" 
                    label="name" 
                    track-by="CAS_id"
                    select-label="Seleccionar casa"
                    @input="sebreCodiCasa()" 
                    id="llicases">
                </multiselect>            
            </div>
            <br>

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="reviewTbl" >
                <thead>
                    <tr align=center>
                        <th>N&uacute;mero de Registre</th>
                        <th>Codi Casa</th>
                        <th>Nom Casa</th>
                        <th>Data</th>
                        <th>Comentari</th>
                        <th>Actiu</th>
                        <th>T&iacute;tul</th>
                        <th>N&uacute;mero de Reserva</th>
                        <th>Puntuaci&oacute;</th>
                        <th>Funcions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody align=center>
                    <tr v-for="review in provaReview" :key="review.REV_id">
                        <th>{{review.REV_id}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_codiCasa}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.CAS_nom}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_data}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_comentari}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_actiu}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_title}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.RES_id}}</th>
                        <th>{{review.REV_rating}}</th>
                        <th><button v-on:click="editReview(review)" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-edit" title="Editar"></i></button></th>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

El codigo del script es el siguiente:

```html
<script>
export default 
   {
       name: 'TaulaReviews',
       data()
       {
            return{ 
            cases: [], 
            reviews: [],
            reviewEdit:[],
            loading: false, 
            selecCasacodi: '',    
            //agrupar: [],
            nou_registre: '', 
            provaReview: [],
            options: [],
            optionValues: [],
            afegit: false,
            forceRender:false
            //canvi: 0,
            //componentKey: 0,
           };
       },

       watch: {
           sebreForce(){
               if (forceRerender){
                   this.makeDataTable();
               }
           }
       },
       methods:
       {
           async getCases() // funcio asincrona getCases
           {
               await Promise.all([
                   axios.get("/getLlistaCases"),
                   axios.get("/getReviews")
               ])
               .then(([cases, reviews]) => {
                   this.cases = cases.data;
                   this.reviews = reviews.data;
                   this.reviews.forEach(review => 
                   {
                       var casareview = this.cases.filter(casa => casa.CAS_id == review.REV_codiCasa);
                   })
                   
                   this.cases.forEach(casa => {
                       this.options.push(
                        {
                            CAS_id: casa.CAS_id,
                            name: casa.CAS_nom
                        });
                   });
                   console.log(reviews);
               })
                .catch(error => 
                {
                    console.log(error);
                })
           },
             makeDataTable() {
                //Destroy data table
                $('#reviewTbl').DataTable().destroy();
                // Inicializate data table
                //$('#reviewTbl').DataTable().clear();
                var table = $('#reviewTbl').DataTable({
                    "language": {
                        //Posa la datatable en espanyol
                        "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.16/i18n/Spanish.json"
                    },
                    "aaSorting": [],
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 'no-sort',
                        "orderable": false,
                    }],
                    "order": [
                        [0, "desc"]
                    ]
                });
            },
     
            newReview() 
            {
                if(this.optionValues.CAS_id == undefined)
                {
                    alert("S'ha d'escollir una casa abans de clicar afegir review");
                    return false;            
                }
                this.afegit = true;
                this.$emit("newReview", this.afegit);
            },
 
            editReview(review)
            {
                this.editant = true;
                this.$emit("editReview", this.editant,review);
            },
           async sebreCodiCasa()
            {
                await axios.get('getCasaReview/' + this.optionValues.CAS_id)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.provaReview = response.data;
                    if(this.provaReview.length == 0)
                    {
                        toast({type: 'error',title: 'No hi ha registres a mostrar. Seleccioni una altre casa'});
                    }
                    this.$nextTick(() => {
                            this.makeDataTable();
                        });
                })
                this.$emit("sebreCodiCasa", this.optionValues.CAS_id);
            },         
        },        
        mounted() 
        {
            this.getCases();
        },
    }
</script>
```

La primera vez que realizo una busqueda sale la información pedida, se cambio de casa, arriba me aparece la casa seleccionada pero no me enseña la información de esta.
He revisado el codigo y no consigo ver porque la segunda vez no da la información y la primera si. Y hasta que no realizo un refresco manual no funciona de nuevo.
Le he dado vueltas y más vueltas y no consigo ver porque la segunda vez no funciona como toca.
Gracias.

En el caso del padre tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<template>
<div>
    <LlistaReviews :afegit="afegit" @newReview="newReview" :selecCasacodi='selecCasacodi' @sebreCodiCasa='sebreCodiCasa' @editReview='editReview'></LlistaReviews>
    <AddReview :forceRender='forceRender' :afegit="afegit" v-if="afegit" :selecCasacodi='selecCasacodi' @closeAfegir="closeAfegir" @forceRerender='forceRerender'></AddReview>
    <AddReview :editant="editant" :reviewEdit="reviewEdit" v-if="editant" :selecCasacodi='selecCasacodi' @closeEditar="closeEditar" @editReview='editReview'></AddReview>
</div>
<!-- Sempre passar l'event al component perque sapiga de on ve -->
```

```js
<script>
    import LlistaReviews from "./LlistaReviews.vue"
    import AddReview from "./AddReview.vue"
   export default 
   {
       components:
       {
           LlistaReviews,
           AddReview
       },
       name: 'ReviewsPare', // assignam nom component, ReviewsPare es l'etiqueta
       data()
       {
           return{
               afegit: false,
               selecCasacodi: '',
               editant: false,
               forceRender:false,
               reviewEdit:[]
               //componentKey: 0
           };
       },
       methods:
       {
           newReview(afegit)
           {
               this.afegit = afegit;
               //$('#reviewTbl').DataTable().reload;
           },
           closeAfegir()
           {
               this.afegit = false;
           },
           closeEditar()
           {
               this.editant = false;
           },


        //    editReview(editar)
        //    {
        //        this.editar = editar;
        //    },

           editReview(editant,review)
           {
               this.editant = editant;
               this.reviewEdit = review;
           },
           
           sebreCodiCasa(codiCasa)
           {
               this.selecCasacodi = codiCasa;
           },

           forceRerender()
           {
               this.forceRender = true;
           },
        },
        mounted() 
        {
            
        } 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Se ejecuta este metodo sebreCodiCasa mas de una vez?

Comment: has comprobado si: this.$emit("sebreCodiCasa", this.optionValues.CAS_id); le llega al padre?

Comment: En el caso de sebreCodiCasa, se ejecuta cada vez que se selecciona una casa. Arriba en la parte superior de la pantalla tengo un input donde sale el codigo de la casa i este cambia cada vez que selecciono una casa nueva. Lo que no sale es la información de la segunda casa seleccionada y posteriores.

Comment: En respueata a Christian, te dejo el codigo que hay en el padre.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado sobra este trozo de codigo.

```js
  this.$nextTick(() => {
                            this.makeDataTable();
                        });
```

Gracias.